# CKEDITOR autogrow focus delay & styling

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, autogrow

When converting an iOS web view with multiple stacked editors to autogrow plugin, I have the following issues:

1. I had default margin, font, and font size styling in the editor which is now ignored - I've tried setting this styling everywhere I can think of to no effect - can these be changed?
2. The editors respect the minimum height, but only seem to get focus if tapped near the top of the editor content space.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could figure out was to edit plugin.js directly, in replaceCache():

```
if ( body ) {
                 body.setStyle( 'font-family', 'Avenir Next' );
                 body.setStyle( 'font-size', '13pt' );
                body.setStyle( 'height', 'auto' );
                body.setStyle( 'width', 'auto' );
                body.setStyle( 'min-height', CKEDITOR.env.safari ? '0%' : 'auto' ); // Safari does not support 'min-height: auto'.
        }
```